# Applying to MSc vs PhD in CS with science background in US

Tags: phd, graduate-school, graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science

I hold a BSc and MSc in physics and want to do graduate studies in CS. I did computational and theoretical research and thesis on quantum memories which are useful in quantum communications (not sure if that sounds any interesting to CS admission committees). But I have not officially taken CS foundations courses (well, except some through Coursera and edX). I am willing to pay for a decent Masters program through loans and part-time work though. Here are my questions from you:

1. Can I improve my odds of getting into a decent department by applying to Masters programs instead of PhD programs?
2. Besides full score on GRE quantitative, I got a decent score in GRE physics. Can any of these make up for my lack of formal education in CS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm no expert, but with research experience and already having a Masters in physics, I think that you should directly apply to the PhD programs.  During your first two years, you're going to take courses anyway.  So **unless** you don't think that you'll be able to handle those courses, I think that doing another masters and then your PhD will be a waste of time and money.  It depends on where you want to go, but a lot of schools will make you take courses in your PhD even if you already have a masters in CS.